# Unbalanced parenthesis and missing operator in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

The following code generates "Unbalanced parenthesis" on on the command prompt at the start and end of the for loop as well as "Missing Operator" at the end of the for loop. However, the code works fine. I found in other related question that it happens majorly due to nested brackets but even that is not present here.

```
for /R .\sql_queries %%m in (*.sql) do (
Echo Querying: %%~nm
::Querying with GAT  - Refer "for /?" for help on %%x variables 
java -Xms64m -Xmx512m -cp %mypath% com.app.GenericAxlTool -i %ip% -v 6.0 -a %axlVer% -d %DBVer% -u %userName% -p %password% -c sqlselect -f %%m >output.tmp
cd sql
ren *.tsv %%~nm.tsv >output.tmp
move %%~nm.tsv ..\Reports >output.tmp
cd..
)
```

Comment: are you sure that all the errors are coming from the bat script? But not from the java code? what do you have in GenericAxlTool class ?

Comment: Do any variable contain a bracket.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `delayed expansion`?

Comment: nothing to do with the error, but I assume, you want to append to "output.tmp". To append to a file, use `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: @npocmakayes errors are coming from BAT only. That class is just for calling webservices.

Comment: @tonybd No. Code is as shown.

Comment: If a filename contains a bracket then so will %%m. If using notepad to write it copy and paste into wordpad to check line breaks. Notepad totally ignores and hides carriage returns but other programs don't. Notepad only looks for line feeds. If coping from browser based documentation such as web pages and help systems sometimes stray carriage returns get invisibly inserted in notepad.

Comment: Plus you have variables like %ip%, do any of them have a bracket. Try echoing out each variable first, and also %%m asap in the code to see if that is so and if the code fails at the start or in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to produce "Unbalanced parenthesis." and "Missing operator." is with `set /a` command:

```
>set /a (
Missing operand.

>set /a (-1
Unbalanced parenthesis.
```

but in the code you posted there's no `SET /A` invoke.

So or there's `set /a` as a string in some of your variables , or it fails in another part of your script.

Comment: set /A STARTTIME=(1%STARTTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%STARTTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%STARTTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%STARTTIME:~9,2%-100)

can u guide me here?

Comment: @MalTec how `STARTTIME` is created? What it contains?

Comment: using %time% variable is bad idea because time setting might/will vary on different machines.Do you have installed powershell?

Comment: yes. I use starttime and endtime just to measure the execution time. So will it matter? And what's the solution to set /a starttime and parenthesis?

Comment: @MalTec better use `for /f %%t in ('powershell "(get-date).tofiletime()"') do set starttime=%%t`  it will set the time directly in milliseconds from 1,1,1900 . And will not depend on your time settings.

Comment: @MalTec and this is a script that will set the current time in millisecond and will not depend neither on installed powershell neither in activated WSH nor on installed `.NET`  - http://pastebin.com/e4qLFiyN

Answer (score 0):

UIAM Batch code doesn't have an "Unbalanced parenthesis" error message - it just fails silently.

It would seem than that the error is coming from the Java code.

Comment: what UIAM means? even urbandictionary has no such thing :-)

Comment: It means "`Unless I am mistaken`" and you've shown that I am.  set /a has that error message.  :)

Comment: I don't have java in my code, just Win CMD; getting Unbalanced parenthesis.
Missing operator. errors when I surround code with brackets () to make a codeblock. Execution is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

CMD shell has been programmed to interpret the first close bracket `)` to be associated with 1st open bracket `(` in code blocks.

I got same errors when grouping codes in brackets.
Found a discussion here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html

Might help someone with workarounds.